# convert a scatter plot into a contour plot in matplotllib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I have the following scatter plot where I plotted using ALPHA=0.2
This allowed me to show areas with lower populations in a lighter shade and the higher ones (due to overlay) in a darker color. I plotted this in matplotlib using 2    1D (one dimensional ) numpy arrays.

[image]

I wanted to do the following instead

[image]

The colous vary depending on the population, blue is low and red is high population. I know I need to bin the data and then plot it but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this in python/matplotlib?

Comment: Thank you - this looks promising, I will try it out.

Comment: Patrick, I went ahead and closed this question as a duplicate.  If it's not, let me know.

Comment: No that's fine thank you. I just wanted to know in the question you asked, if using the hist2d can I color "white" where there is no data instead of dark blue?

Comment: Sure, there are several ways you can do that. The easiest is to mask the 0 values. E.g. `counts = np.ma.masked_equal(counts, 0)`, if `counts` is your 2D array of counts.  (Note that at that point it's easiest to use `np.histogram2d` and `pcolormesh`.) As a quick example: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/7517ded854aaffc8254a